# MySQL Slow performance with count() of matching records in a joined table

Tags: mysql

There is a table called "basket_status" in the query below.  For each record in basket_status, a count of yarn balls in the basket is being made from another table (yarn_ball_updates).

The basket_status table has 761 rows.   The yarn_ball_updates table has 1,204,294 records. Running the query below takes about 30 seconds to 60 seconds (depending on how busy the server is) and returns 750 rows.  Obviously my problem is doing a match against 1,204,294 records for all of the 761 basket_status records.

I tried making a view based on the query but offered no performance increase.  I believe I read that for views you can't have sub queries and complex joins.

What direction should I take to speed up this query?   I've never made a MySQL scheduled task or anything, but it seems like the "basket_status" table should have a  "yarn_ball_count" count already in it, and an automated process should be updating that new extra count() column maybe?

Thanks for any help or direction.

```
SELECT p.id, p.basket_name, p.high_quality, p.yarn_ball_count
FROM (
SELECT q.id, q.basket_name, q.high_quality,
CAST(SUM(IF (q.report_date = mxd.mxdate,1,0)) AS CHAR) yarn_ball_count
FROM (
SELECT bs.id, bs.basket_name, bs.high_quality,ybu.report_date
FROM yb.basket_status bs
JOIN yb.yarn_ball_updates ybu ON bs.basket_name = ybu.alpha_pmn
) q,
(SELECT MAX(ybu.report_date) mxdate FROM yb.yarn_ball_updates ybu) mxd
GROUP BY q.basket_name, q.high_quality ) p
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you need nested queries for this.  I'm not a MySQL developer but won't this work?

```
SELECT bs.id, bs.basket_name, bs.high_quality, count(*) yarn_ball_count
FROM yb.basket_status bs
     JOIN yb.yarn_ball_updates ybu ON bs.basket_name = ybu.alpha_pmn
     JOIN (SELECT MAX(ybu.report_date) mxdate FROM yb.yarn_ball_updates) mxd ON ybu.report_date = mxd.mxdate
GROUP BY bs.basket_name, bs.high_quality
```